# How to turn off debugging on a project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, multiple-projects, jdwp

My situation demands I have two copies of the same project. One is for development, the other is for debugging, testing and single stepping to understand the existing workflow.

As a consequence I have two copies of the same project. I would like both copies to behave exactly the same way except that the first project should not take part in debugging. All the **JDWP** [Java Debug Wire Protocol] attempts to connect and debug the remote Java process should be with respect to the untouched dedicated copy of the project that was checked out recently.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Whyn't just "Run" the "development" version and "Debug" the "debug" version?  Seems like a strange set of testing requirements.  In "Run" mode it won't break at specified breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple debug/run configuration for the same or different projects in Eclipse.

Assume that you have a single Java project and you want to

1. Test your application with some VM arguments and
2. Without any VM arguments.

Then Go to Debug->Debug Configuration and select Java application. Create debug(launch) configuration for your project and select main class of your Java project.

For 1 go to Arguments tab in the VM text area add the arguments

For 2. Leave this blank

Thus you can debug single Java project with multiple debug configuration.

In your case you MUST create debug configuration ONLY for that project you want to debug.